# How to enable company-mode for some buffers only?

Tags: auctex, company

I would like company mode to lead automatically for some buffers like AucTex  for example but not on other buffers like Org-mode

```
global-company-mode
```

Enables comapny mode everywhere and I only want to set it locally

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `company-mode` in a few major modes, use a [hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html).

```lisp
;; turn on company mode for all modes derived from prog-mode, and cmake-mode
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'company-mode)
(add-hook 'cmake-mode-hook 'company-mode)
```

If you want to disable `company-mode` in a few major modes, use a hook.

```lisp
;; enable company-mode everywhere except text-mode and cmake-mode
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (company-mode -1))
(add-hook 'cmake-mode-hook (company-mode -1))
```

Check your major mode's documentation for the exact name of its hook.

Answer (score 2):

`company` comes with a variable called `company-global-modes`.  The docstring says:

> Modes for which `company-mode` mode is turned on by
>   `global-company-mode`. If `nil`, means no modes.  If `t`, then all major
>   modes have it turned on. If a list, it should be a list of
>   `major-mode` symbol names for which `company-mode` should be
>   automatically turned on.  The sense of the list is negated if it
>   begins with `not`.  For example:
>   `(c-mode c++-mode)`
>   means that `company-mode` is turned on for buffers in C and C++ modes only.
>   `(not message-mode)`
>   means that `company-mode` is always turned on except in
>   `message-mode` buffers.

Customize this variable acc. to your needs.  Or in your init file, write something like this:

```
(setq company-global-modes '(not org-mode))
```